# Please how can I get Jira to identify my newly created team? I think there's a way Teams has to be created in admin setting for us to filter with Team

Tags: jira, jql, jira-agile

I'm trying to create a new Scrum Board in Jira, but while pulling the query to create the board, the team is unidentified by Jira, so that points to the fact that we can't filter by Teams in that instance. My admin was unable to find it, probably because he's very busy with other stuff. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

We are facing the same issue and can not find a working solution.

As a suggestion, you can use components, user groups or by selecting every user one by one.